# How to Autogenerate the cube and dimension design from the Builder Schema file in icCube?

Tags: schema, auto-generate, iccube

I want to document the model design in the Builder in icCube. Initially it will not be too much work to document it using MS Visio or something similar, but I foresee the issues when the model will get changed over time with designs not matching the real deal.

Is there a way to generate (parts of) the documentation from the Builder?

Comment: I've removed my initial response; please give an example of what you'd like to do.

Comment: I would like to be able to automatically generate pictures like the ones presented in "The DataWarehouse Toolkit" from Ralph Kimball. So data experts can also understand how columns are used in the icCube model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's why we usually don't make documentation on the code, it seldom survives changes and might be a source of misunderstanding if it's too detailled.

There is nothing in the current version, but we are working on dev to have some graphs 
that might help to get an overview of the model. Not really for documentation.

[image]

Comment: This is really helping, I see it is active in the latest version (7.3). Thanks.